# Group elements of a column into mulitple subgroups SQL

Tags: sql

I am looking at different breeds of cattle and their `AnimalTypeCode` , `BreedCateoryID` and resultant `Growth`.

I have the following query

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,[KillDate])
        ,[AnimalTypeCode]
        ,AVG([Growth])
        ,[BreedCategoryID]
  FROM [dbo].[tblAnimal]
  WHERE (AnimalTypeCode='C'
        or AnimalTypeCode= 'E')
    GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy,[KillDate])
        ,[AnimalTypeCode]
        ,[BreedCategoryID]
    GO
```

This query is good and gives me almost what I want, but  `BreedCategoryID` is numbered 1 through 7 and I would like to group them:

```
(1 = Pure Dairy),
(2 and 3 = Dairy)
(4, 5, 6 and 7 = Beef)
```

So instead of getting the mean `Growthrate` for each `BreedCategoryID` I would like to get the average for Pure Dairy, Dairy, and Beef.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a new "variable" using `cross apply` in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT YEAR(KillDate]), a.AnimalTypeCode, v.grp,
        AVG([Growth])
FROM [dbo].[tblAnimal] a CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN a.BreedCategoryID IN (1) THEN 'Pure Dairy'
                   WHEN a.BreedCategoryID IN (2, 3) THEN 'Dairy'
                   WHEN a.BreedCategoryID IN (4, 5, 6, 7) THEN 'Beef'
              END)
     ) as v(grp)
WHERE a.AnimalTypeCode IN ('C', 'E')
GROUP BY YEAR(KillDate]), a.AnimalTypeCode, v.grp;
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases and qualified all the column references.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculations in a *derived table* (the subquery). `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select killyear, [AnimalTypeCode], AVG([Growth]), BreedCat
(
  SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,[KillDate]) killyear
        ,[AnimalTypeCode]
        ,[Growth]
        ,case when [BreedCategoryID] = 1 then 'Pure Dairy'
              when [BreedCategoryID] in (2, 3) then 'Dairy'
              when [BreedCategoryID] in (4, 5, 6, 7) then 'Beef'
         end BreedCat
  FROM [dbo].[tblAnimal]
  WHERE (AnimalTypeCode='C'
        or AnimalTypeCode= 'E')
) dt
GROUP BY killyear
        ,[AnimalTypeCode]
        ,BreedCat
```